# Existence of induced subgraph with desired properties

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I was reading the proof of the following proposition [image]

This proof is not detailed so I've decided to provide some details to understand it better. For convenience assume that $G_0:=G$ and $|V_{G_0}|>1$.

1. If for all $v\in V_{G_0}$ we have $d_{\text{ave}}(G_0-v)<d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$ (which is equivalent to $d(v)>\frac{1}{2}d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$), then we can take $H$ to be $G_0$.

2. If for some $v_0\in V_{G_0}$ we have $d_{\text{ave}}(G_0-v_0)\geq d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$ (which is equivalent to $d(v_0)\leq\frac{1}{2}d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$), then we delete vertex $v_0$ and consider the graph $G_1:=G_0-v_0$.

We apply the same procedure to $G_1$.

*So my question is the following:* Is it possible that we will end up with empty set? Suppose it is, then we'll get a sequence of vertices $\{v_k\}_{k=0}^{n-1}$ (where $|V_{G_0}|=n$) such that $v_k\in V_{G_k}$ where $G_{k+1}:=G_k-v_k$ such that $d(v_k)\leq \frac{1}{2}d_{\text{ave}}(G_k)$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$.

Is it possible to derive some contradiction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step, the average degree of $G_k$ is at least the average degree of $G$, so it is not possible to delete all but one vertex of $G$, as a single vertex graph has average degree $0$.

Comment: Let me clarify one moment: If it would be possible then for each $0\leq k \leq n-1$ we have $d_{\text{ave}}(G_k)\geq d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$. In particular $d_{\text{ave}}(G_{n-1})\geq d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)$ but $G_{n-1}$ is a graph with one vertex and hence $d_{\text{ave}}(G_{n-1})=0$ and this is a contradiction because $d_{\text{ave}}(G_0)>0$ (actually for contradiction we need to assume that $G_0$ has at least one edge, right?). Am I right?

Comment: Excuse me, is this what you meant?

Comment: @PlayGame yes and if $G$ has no edges, then $H=G$ suffices.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your answer!